# Schedule Informatica Workflow Yearly and Quarterly without Unix Script

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I want to achieve following things in Informatica PowerCentre

1)I want to schedule Informatica Workflow "Yearly" which starts from Dec-Nov.
So on every 1st Of December that workflow should run.

2)I also want to schedule another workflow "Quarterly" which starts from:
a)Dec-Feb (On every 1st Dec workflow should run)
b)Mar-May (On every 1st Mar workflow should run)
c)Jun-Aug (On every 1st Jun workflow should run)
d)Sep-Nov (On every 1st Sep workflow should run)

Could it be possible with Workflow Scheduler option only. I don't want use UNIX Script. Please let me know.

Comment: I have tried to do it from Informatica Workflow scheduler option. But there is no option available from where we can achieve solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it in following way:

1) For Yearly Workflow Scheduler(Dec-Nov).See attached image.[Yearly Workflow Scheduler (Dec-Nov)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFwaP.jpg)

2) For Quarterly Scheduler.See attached image.[Quarterly Scheduler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ii7G.jpg)
   a)Dec-Feb
   b)Mar-May
   c)Jun-Aug
   d)Sep-Nov

Answer (score 0):

Please try under `Schedule` set to `Customized Repeat`, edit the Customized Repeat settings to set `Repeat every` to `12` and choose `Month(s)`. Next, in the `Monthly` area specify `Run on day` as `1`.
Now the tricky part: you need to `Schedule the Workflow` somewhere between 2nd and 30th of November... It will execute on 1st day of new month and schedule itself to run again in next 12 months.

This is weak: if scheduled again (e.g. in case of IS reboot) it will execute on 1st day of nearest month. In general Workflow Scheduler has many weeknesses and I'd recommend using external one.